# SharePoint 2010 file.aspx is not compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to include some static content into a SharePoint 2010 master page. I am trying to achieve this by creating an aspx file and registering it in the master page template. The code is below:

footer.aspx:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#"
 compilationMode="Always" %>

 <div id="testfooter">hello from test footer</div>
```

in master page:

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="Footer" Src="/location/footer.aspx" %>

 <UserControl:Footer id="IdFooter" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        </UserControl:Footer>
```

I am getting the error

```
 Error 

 The user control '/location/footer.aspx' is not compiled, and can only be used dynamically. To force it to be compiled, set compilationMode="Always" in its @control directive.
```

Any help much appreciated, I don't like SharePoint.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

A user control is an .ascx file, so I am not sure if you have made it correctly. You cannot just add pages to master page. You can only add controls.

SharePoint has further restrictions over what code you can run within it.

To work with SharePoint you would have to:

1. Create your user control within a SharePoint solution.
2. Register your dll with SharePoint
3. Activate the solution
4. Add the UserControl to a page or master page.

Comment: By moving my file to the CONTROLTEMPLATES folder I was able to use it successfully and do what I was wanting to do. Is there a better location to put it as I do not like changing the contents of this folder?